# Identity provider vs authentication provider

Tags: linux, ldap, single-sign-on, sssd

What is the difference between an identity provider and an authentication provider? This is specifically for System Security Services Daemon(SSSD) in Redhat 6/7. I assume the identity provider is like Google or Facebook providing logins to 3rd party website but I'm not sure what an authentication provider does?

Answer (score -1):

The Identity Provider specifies the details of the identity back end to use for the "Security" domain.

The id_provider parameter specifies the type of provider.
The common ones are:

- ldap
- ipa (Identity Management in Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
- ad (Microsoft Active Directory)
- proxy, for a legacy NSS provider, such as nss_nis. Using a proxy ID provider also requires specifying the legacy NSS library to load to start successfully, set in the proxy_lib_name option.
- local, the SSSD internal local provider

The Authentication Provider directive specifies the authentication provider used for the domain. If NOT specified, the iIdentity Provider is used. Supported authentication providers are:

- ldap: Native LDAP authentication
- krb5: Kerberos authentication
- proxy: Relays authentication to some other PAM target
- none: Disables authentication explicitly

The best references for SSSD are https://sssd.io/, https://access.redhat.com/ and of course Google.